# react-native-router-flux undifine is not a function (evaluationg 'addListner')

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I upgraded my router-flux version 0.27 to 0.30.
I am facing error of evaluating addListner I also submit it in the [issue](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/issues/3008)

[image]

Comment: v0.30? It's at `4.0.0-beta.28` now.

Comment: If I upgraded to 0.28 issue https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/issues/2808 is facing

Comment: So what version are you at? `4.0.0-beta.30`?!

Comment: yes V4.0.0-beta.30

Comment: The latest version on npm is `4.0.0-beta.28`. You downloaded and used the latest source on Github?

Comment: yes I did it but still facing same issue https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/issues/2808

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`4.0.0-beta.30` is broken as the last commit says

> update dependencies, bump version - don't use, errors are possible!

`4.0.0-beta.28` is broken too. Use `4.0.0-beta.27` instead.

In `package.json`, make sure you have exactly this:

```
"react-native-router-flux": "4.0.0-beta.27"
```

Don't include `^` otherwise your package manager will still install the `.28` version (unless you have a `yarn.lock` at `.27`).